# JAVAFX creating a JavaDB table

Tags: javafx, database-connection, javadb

I have a form which upon releasing the "submit" button I want to create a table or find the previously created table and then write the form data into the table. Here is the problem, for some reason I cant get the current code to create a new table within my database. Can someone take a look at my current code and tell me where I'm going wrong.

Here is the code for the button from the form controller:

```
@FXML
private void OnRelease_hazard(MouseEvent event) {
   Connection c ;
    final String HAZARD_TABLE =
    "CREATE TABLE HAZARD ("+
    "ID          INTEGER NOT NULL "+
    "PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY "+
    "(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)," +
    "SYNAME           VARCHAR(50)," +
    "CLASSIFICATION         VARCHAR(40)," +
    "ENVIROMENT      VARCHAR(40)," +
    "EVENT    VARCHAR(100)" +
    "DESCRIPTION    VARCHAR(2000)" +
    "JUSTIFICATION    VARCHAR(2000)" +
    "DEFINITION    VARCHAR(2000)" +
    "SCORE         INTEGER )";

    try{
    c = DBConnect.connect();
    Statement sta = c.createStatement();
    int count = sta.executeUpdate(HAZARD_TABLE);
    System.out.println("table created.");
    sta.close();

    c.close(); 
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error on Building Data");             
      }
  }
```

here is the connection class:

```
package MAAT;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class DBConnect {

private static Connection conn; 
private static String url = "jdbc:derby:testdatabase";  
private static String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";

public static Connection connect() throws SQLException{ 
    try{
System.setProperty("derby.database.forceDatabaseLock", "true"); 
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){ 
        System.err.println("Error: "+cnfe.getMessage()); 
    }catch(InstantiationException ie){ 
        System.err.println("Error: "+ie.getMessage()); 
    }catch(IllegalAccessException iae){ 
        System.err.println("Error: "+iae.getMessage()); 
    } 
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password"); 
    return conn; 
} 

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{ 
    if(conn !=null && !conn.isClosed()) 
        return conn; 
    connect(); 
    return conn; 
}     
}
```

trace:

```
Executing C:\Users\Brandon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MAAT\dist\run1950342611\MAAT.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\jre/bin/java
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Node
at MAAT.MainScreenController.handleButtonAction_newmenu(MainScreenController.java:251)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Error: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:MAAWBdatabase
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
Error on Building Data
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at MAAT.DBConnect.connect(DBConnect.java:33)
at MAAT.IdThreat_HazardController.OnRelease_hazard(IdThreat_HazardController.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: So what actually happens? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: here is the error I get - Error: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:MAAWBdatabase
Error on Building Data

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace. Does the database already exist?

Comment: the stack trace has been added, the error in discussion starts  @ Error: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver. yes, the database does exist already.

Comment: It looks like you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException` (which you would see if you logged the full stack trace in your catch blocks in `connect()`). So you haver not included the derby jar file on your classpath.